# Symlinks get messed up in TFS

Tags: ios, tfs, jenkins, crashlytics

I have Crashlytics installed onto my app and building perfectly on my local machine.

But after pushing into a TFS repository, Jenkins build server fail to build the project.

I had two setup trials:-

**1- Normal Setup (i.e. Dragging .framework file into proj)**

I get this error:-

> fatal error: 'Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h' file not found
>
> import Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h
>
> ```
>     ^ 1 error generated.
> ```

**2- Installing via CocoaPods**

I get this error:-

```
file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x56 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x73 0x2F 0x43 0x75 0x72 0x72 0x65 0x6E 0x74 ) which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): {PATH}/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Crashlytics", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any clues on how to fix this error either ways?

** Update **

I noticed that the symlinks inside Crashlytics.framework are all messed up (i.e. Crashlytics symlink opens a text file with Versions/Current/Crashlytics)

Answer (score 3):

Okay I kinda fixed it.
It appears that TFS doesn't play well with symlinks, thus Crashlytics.framework is messed up on Jenkins.

So to fix that I added this script file *FixCrashlytics.sh* which has the following:-

> ```
> pushd "${WORKSPACE}"/Crashlytics.framework/Versions
> ln -sfn A Current
> popd
>
> pushd "${WORKSPACE}"/Crashlytics.framework
> ln -sfn Versions/Current/Headers Headers
> ln -sfn Versions/Current/Resources Resources
> ln -sf Versions/Current/Crashlytics Crashlytics
> popd
> ```

Then I ran the following line in **Build Execute Shell**

> `sh "${WORKSPACE}/FixCrashlytics.sh"`

Hope that helps someone, someday.